# How to keep words on a single line

Tags: html

How can I keep this two words on a single line:

```
<div align=right>hai</div> 
<div align=center>hello</div>
```

I have already tried it but I didn't get any satisfactory preview.

Comment: Post the code please

Answer (score 1):

Divs are block elements by default so they will appear on separate lines.

You can set them to inline by css: display:inline

Or use an inline element like

or

```html
<span align=right>hai</span> 
<span align=center>hello</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you wanted only DIV tag**

Simply, use `display:inline-block` with DIV tag.

```css
div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div align=right>hai</div> 
<div align=center>hello</div>
```

## Update

You can even use `style` attribute like below:

```
<div style="display:inline-block">hai</div>    
<div style="display:inline-block">hello</div>
```

But, it's not a good practice...

Comment: Should I keep the CSS under <style> tag?

Comment: @S.S You can also use `style` attribute too..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I correcctly understand your question, but I'll try an answer anyway.

Let's say you have 2 words in a sentance :

```
<p>word1 word2</p>
```

and you want this 2 words to be, at any resolution, displayed beside each other.

Replace the space between this 2 words by `&nbsp;` (code for non-breaking space in HTML), and it will be displayed as a single entity :

```
<p>word1&nbsp;word2</p>
```